# Applying a diff patch

Tags: diff, patch

I've never patched anything in Linux, and I can't exactly figure out what the guy who wrote [this post](https://justreadthecode.wordpress.com/tag/firmware/) (second paragraph) means. That target source is `qemu` from github and the changes to apply are:

```
diff --git a/linux-user/flatload.c b/linux-user/flatload.c
index 58f679e..c13a201 100644
--- a/linux-user/flatload.c
+++ b/linux-user/flatload.c
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@
 #define ntohl(x) be32_to_cpu(x)
 #include 
 
-//#define DEBUG
+#define DEBUG
 
 #ifdef DEBUG
 #define        DBG_FLT(...)    printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This looks like a long `diff` command to me but attempting to execute it fails. After some searching, I though I had to save that as ie `qemu.patch` and run it with `patch`, but after trying a few combinations that failed as well.

In this context, what am I supposed to do with the above snippet?

Comment: It's hard to answer questions like this when you just say "fails". How did it fail? What did it tell you?

Comment: It would probably be easier to just open `flatload.c` and uncomment the line manually...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually a *very short* diff command. It says to remove the line `//#define DEBUG` and replace it with `#define DEBUG`.

In this diff format, lines starting with a single `-` are removed and those with `+` are added. The other lines are for context, and the `@@` tells the offset into the file and number of lines referenced. (And the triple `+++` `---` lines tell you which file was modified.)

The two common reasons for a patch to fail to apply are:

1. The actual affected lines have changed, or
2. The context around those lines has changed (possibly, *changed too much*, because patch usually uses a "fuzzy" algorithm.

In this case, it's probably easiest to look at the section of code by hand (in the `linux-user/flatload.c` file, as you can see from the first line), and see if there's a commented-out `#define DEBUG` anywhere, and then remove the `//` comment characters.

Looking at the code myself, I see that the problem is probably actually reason #3 — the patch is mangled because it's been rendered in a way it wasn't supposed to be. See that line that just says `#include`? In the [original source](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=linux-user/flatload.c;h=566a7a87a3452055fbac5aac88c18d58ee60f3a3;hb=HEAD), it says `#include <target_flat.h>`. The blog software where you found the patch probably decided that `<target_flat.h>` is a suspicious HTML tag and silently deleted it, and the author didn't notice.

Comment: I remember there being a flag to `patch` regarding the directory depth; perhaps that is throwing them off?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah, yes —  `-p0` or `-p1` or whatever. Since I labeled something else as reason #3, that'll have to be reason #4. :)

Answer (score 2):

This patch looks like it was created using `git`, specifically [the `git diff` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).  So you'd probably do well to use the git tools ([specifically `git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)) to patch it onto the target file(s):

```
git apply qemu.patch
```

Comment: Yeah, although in this case, that won't work because of the error in the patch.